# How to handle server side errors in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I handle server side errors with angularjs. I saw a few solutions, like [How to properly handle server side errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254714/how-to-properly-handle-server-side-errors), but they don't really fit my needs/maybe I need to change my failing behavior. Note that I am handling the routing on server side.

My problem is that on server side I run a few `mongo` queries which I return to my routes. Note that these queries may generate custom errors as well (like a field's length is not appropriate). E.g.:

**Server Side**

ingredientController

```
controller.getIngredient = function(cb) {
    Ingredient.findOne({},cb)
}
```

in my route handler I call this function:

```
function(req, res) {
ingredientController.getIngredient(function(err, data) {
    if (err)
        res.json({
            error: 1
        })
    else
        res.json({
            error: 0,
            data: 'success'
        })
})
}
```

*Note that in the json could contain the error message as well.*

**Client Side**

```
productServices.getIngredient()
        .success(function(result) {
             //error should be handled here e.g. result.error === 1
             $scope.ingredient = result.data
        })
        .error(function(err) {
             console.log('error ' + err)
        })
```

Am I doing it right? If yes, then how should I give some feedback to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create a service and directive that displays the error message. Load up the directive in your main template and then use the service to update it.

Another option is to use the [angular-growl](https://github.com/marcorinck/angular-growl) library:

```
angular.module('MyModule').service(
  'MyService',
  function (growl) {
    this.getDatabaseResult = function () {
      getResult().then(
        function (result) {
          growl.addSuccessMessage('Success!');
        },
        function (error) {
          growl.addErrorMessage('Get Database Result Error: ' + error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: So I need to call this service's `getDatabaseResult` in each `ajax` request's `success` with the `error` parameter? Also could you update your result that it is not general -- you can keep the general form -- but it applies to my exact question?

Comment: @Pio you would call growl's addSuccessMessage or addErrorMessage